# What's the Python equivalent of Julia's `@edit` macro?

Tags: python, julia, read-eval-print-loop

In Julia, calling a function with the [`@edit`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.@edit) macro from the REPL will open the editor and put the cursor at the line where the method is defined. So, doing this:

```
julia> @edit 1 + 1
```

jumps to `julia/base/int.jl` and puts the cursor on the line:

```
(+)(x::T, y::T) where {T<:BitInteger} = add_int(x, y)
```

As does the [function form](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.edit-Tuple%7BAny%7D): `edit(+, (Int, Int))`

Is there an equivalent decorator/function in Python that does the same from the Python REPL?

Comment: No, and editing the function's source code wouldn't take effect anyway unless you restarted Python. (You could try reloading the module, but that's got all sorts of nasty caveats and weird interactions and is completely unreliable.)

Comment: I don't intend to edit the source code of standard Python functions. Most of it is in C anyway. But, it's still useful to be able to easily look at the source code of the external function being called.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking for? Python has no (native) macros, so it cannot have anything "like" ``@edit``. Both decorators and functions work on *values*, not *expressions* so by definition they do not apply. There are some hooks and third-party libraries that allow creating macros, but they are not remotely as common as Julia macros. This seems more like something to be handled by an editor or IDE, not a program itself.

Comment: Many editors provide a "jump to definition" function. Do you know how they do it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, let me clarify. I do not need any specific method. All I care for is a way to look at the source code of the function being called.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi `1 + 1` was just an example. It just so happens that addition on Integers in Juliia is implemented in Julia itself. I do not know if `1 + 1` is implemented as a call to `__add__`. But, if I have a custom class, then I want `a + b` to jump me to the `__add__` method of the class definition to which `a` and `b` belong. Does that clarify things?

Comment: I highly recommend PyCharm

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I'm aware of `help`. But, it doesn't answer the problem in the question.

Comment: The Python REPL is not intended as an IDE. Use a real IDE as suggested above, they usually have a keystroke to take you from a function call to the function definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: In the Python ecosystem, this is not the job of the core language/runtime but rather tools such as IDEs. For example, the [ipython shell](https://ipython.org) has the [`??` special syntax](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#accessing-help) to get improved help including source code.

```py
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:42:08)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import random

In [2]: random.uniform??
Signature: random.uniform(a, b)
Source:
    def uniform(self, a, b):
        "Get a random number in the range [a, b) or [a, b] depending on rounding."
        return a + (b-a) * self.random()
File:      /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/random.py
Type:      method
```

---

The Python runtime itself allows viewing source code *of objects* via [`inspect.getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource). This uses a heuristic to search the source code as available; the objects themselves do not carry their source code.

```py
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 21 2020, 10:42:08)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> print(inspect.getsource(inspect.getsource))
def getsource(object):
    """Return the text of the source code for an object.

    The argument may be a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame,
    or code object.  The source code is returned as a single string.  An
    OSError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
    return ''.join(lines)
```

It is not possible to resolve arbitrary expressions or statements to their source; since all names in Python are resolved dynamically, the vast majority of expressions does not have a well-defined implementation unless executed. A debugger, e.g. as provided by [`pdb.set_trace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace), allows inspecting the expression as it is executed.

Answer (score 1):

In most IDEs like PyCharm or VSCode you can Ctrl+ click on a function / class to get its definition, even if it is in the core language or a 3rd party library (in VSCode, this also works in Julia btw.).

A limitation is that this only works for "pure Python" code, C library code, etc. is not shown.